# How to translate point size in cex into units of plot?

Tags: r, png, points

I try to figure out how big the radii of the points in my plot in x and y direction are going to be, with their size being set by `cex`.

I want to create a plotting function which needs this information.
It appears to me as if `cex` would be this magical parameter and nobody actually knows what exactly it is going to do.

I am creating a plot with the `png` function.
I set a graph width and height.
I set `par(mar)` and `par(oma)`.
I plot an empty plot with an `xlim` and `ylim` being set, and add an additional `xaxs = "i"` and `yaxs = "i"`.
Then I add `points`.

So, my question: How can I deduce from my graph width and height (set in pixels or inches?), my `mar` and  `oma` settings (what is their unit???) and my `xlims` and `ylims` what the extent of e.g. a point with `cex = 2` is going to be?

Comment: By Mr `grid`, Paul Murrel: [symbol size on a plot](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-July/035796.html)

Comment: Great, thanks!
I also found this very helpful document, but I guess I couldn't have figured it out myself...:
https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/how-big-is-your-graph.pdf