# Units of measurement for R features

Tags: r, graph, units-of-measurement

What units are **cex** and size in?

For example,  if I specify that **size** = 3, what does this mean? Pixels? mm? cm?

If I specify that **cex** = 2, is this measured in pixels, mm, cm? I know that **cex** = 2 means that I am making the size of a point 2 times the original size, but if the original size is not specified what is the default size and its units?

I've tried to search for this, but cannot seem to find anything.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51200677/3358272, https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-July/035796.html, and https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/how-big-is-your-graph.pdf.